# from php curl to python urllib (POST to Upload API Problem)

Tags: python, curl, urllib

I tried to convert a php api code to python:

This is the php code:

```
// Variables to Post
$local_file = "/path/to/file"; 
$file_to_upload = array(
 'file'=>'@'.$local_file, 
'convert'=>'1', 
'user'=>'YOUR_USERNAME', 
'password'=>'YOUR_PASSWORD'
); 

// Do Curl Request
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://example.org/dapi.php'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $file_to_upload); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result=curl_exec ($ch); 
curl_close ($ch); 

// Do Stuff with Results
echo $result;
```

And this is my Python Code:

```
url = 'http://example.org/dapi.php'
file ='/path/to/file'
datei= open(file, 'rb').read()

values = {'file' : datei ,
     'user' : 'username',
     'password' : '12345' ,
     'convert': '1'}

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()

print the_page
```

It uploads my files but the response is an Error so that something has to be wrong with my python code. But I can´t see my mistake.

Comment: What error? Also, I assume `'@'.` formats a string in PHP, if not, what does it do? What does `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` do?

Comment: yep, that `@.` is concatenating a string on local file and in python your are reading as it is the file and sending it. It's the only difference I can really see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying a lot of opportunities. I found my solution using pycurl:

```
import pycurl
import cStringIO

url = 'http://example.org/dapi.php'
file ='/path/to/file'


print "Start"
response = cStringIO.StringIO()
c = pycurl.Curl()
values = [('file' , (c.FORM_FILE,  file)),
      ('user' , 'username'),
      ('password' , 'password'),
      ('convert', '1')]


c.setopt(c.POST, 1)
c.setopt(c.URL,url)
c.setopt(c.HTTPPOST,  values)
#c.setopt(c.VERBOSE, 1)
c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, response.write)
c.perform()
c.close()
print response.getvalue()
print "All done"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way to upload a file using multipart/form-data encoding.
There are some snippets you can use, though:

[http://pymotw.com/2/urllib2/index.html#module-urllib2]
[http://code.activestate.com/recipes/146306-http-client-to-post-using-multipartform-data/]

A simpler way would be to use a library.
Some good libraries that I use are:

1. [requests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests)
2. [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/)

Comment: Thank you for the ideas. I´ll check them.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with this line: `datei= open(file, 'rb').read()`. For urllib2.Request to upload a file, it needs an actual file object, so the line should be: `datei= open(file, 'rb')`. `open(...).read()` returns a `str` instead of the file object.

Comment: @isbadawi Sorry about that. Trying to do too much at once.